# Easiest way of converting a regular from to perform submissions via ajax?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, forms

I'm trying to convert simple forms such as:

```
<form action="/api.php", method="get">
... radios, checkboxes etc
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

To perform ajax submission instead of reloading the page when hitting submit using angular.

I plan on removing the submit button and replacing it with a regular button with `ng-click="submit()"`. My submit function would look something like this:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
 $http.get('/api', { params: ??? })
      .success(...));
}
```

However the difficulty I have here is attaching the get params from my form inputs. I'm not sure how to reference them. Would I have to add `ng-model` to every single `input` element?

I have a lot of forms that require "converting" and I was wondering what would be the least intrusive way (least changes to markup) to do this? The reason is because a previous developer has left me with a soup of ugly html changing things will be costly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its EASY.

html

```
<form action="/api.php" ng-submit="submit()">
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

js

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.user = {};
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api.php?name=' + $scope.user.name
    }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
};
```

Comment: I understand this approach but what if I have a form with a thousand inputs? I would have to dig through each and specify `ng-model`. Also I think there's a better way of doing `'/api.php?name=' + $scope.user.name` than just hard coding it.